# How to serialize Scala Map to Json in PlayFramework?

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.2

Looks like Play Json Library is unable to serialize Scala Collections.
Is there any alternative. I just need to dump the data from a map.

```
import scala.concurrent._
import play.api.libs.ws._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import play.libs.Json

object temp {

        // Correct Serialization
        val javaMap = new java.util.HashMap[String, String]()

        javaMap.put("Abc", "Def")

        // Outputs: res1: String = {"Abc":"Def"}
        Json.stringify(Json.toJson(javaMap))


        // Incorrect Serialization
        val scalaMap = Map("Abc" -> "Def")           //> scalaMap  : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(Abc -> Def)

        // Output: res2: String = {"empty":false,"traversableAgain":true}
        Json.stringify(Json.toJson(scalaMap))       //> res2: String = {"empty":false,"traversableAgain":true}

    }
```

Comment: Your sample code doesn't make any sense.  Play-Json can't handle Java collections by default and it has no problem handling a `scala.collection.immutable.Map[String, String]`.  Is this all your code?

Comment: What I am saying is completely opposite. Java collection is handled correctly. Check the output on repl.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're importing the wrong JSON library.

`import play.api.libs.json._`

Comment: Awesome thanks. Its bit confusing which ones to use.

Comment: See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson#Using-Writes-converters "Using Writes converters
Scala to JsValue conversion is performed by the utility method Json.toJson[T](T)(implicit writes: Writes[T]). This functionality depends on a converter of type Writes[T] which can convert a T to a JsValue."